# SQL query to find rows between now and time in long

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I need to run a sql query to find rows of data which falls between a particular interval of 1 hour, 1 day, 1 month  and so on. Here the time of an hour or month I am passing is in millis i.e a long value of time duration So the below query

*`BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL " + timeDuration + ") AND NOW()` - I used to pass my time duration in string (1 hour) while using this query and it worked awesome*

is of no help to me

Can anyone help to get the between query for Long time duration which can be for 1 hour, 1 day , 1 week i.e. 3600000,86400000  and so on

Comment: In a comment you mentioned something about needing a date filter. Please [edit] your question to include your complete requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`TIMESTAMPADD`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampadd) like;)

```
BETWEEN TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR, -1, NOW()) AND NOW()
```

And for day:

```
BETWEEN TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, -1, NOW()) AND NOW()
```

Comment: I want a date filter as well as i have multiple days data

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem just yesterday and I resolved it by finding UNIX timestamp for the `start_time` and the UNIX timestamp for the `end_time` = `start_time + 3600` for a one hour difference

My final SQL query was simply: `"SELECT * FROM *Table* WHERE time > " + str(start_time) + " && time < " + str(end_time)"`

This worked for me - although I'm a bit of a rookie at SQL :) It doesn't use the between route at all - I'm not too sure if this gives a performance hit or not? I'd appreciate any comments on this :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not formulating your `WHERE` clause exactly correctly. Try something like this:

```
WHERE my_datetime BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 3600 SECOND AND NOW()
```

The `INTERVAL...` form of time arithmetic requires you to give the unit of time. The [available units are MICROSECOND, SECOND, MINUTE, HOUR, DAY, WEEK, MONTH, QUARTER, and YEAR.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampadd)

The data type of your `my_datetime` column matters. It's hard to give precise answers unless you disclose it to us.

If your column contains both dates and times and you want to filter on a wide range of dates, you could do this:

```
  WHERE DATE(my_datetime) BETWEEN DATE(NOW()) - 25 YEAR  /* slow !!! */
                              AND DATE(NOW())
```

But, that applies the `DATE()` function to your column, and so prevents the use of an index.

You need this:

```
 WHERE my_datetime >= CURDATE() - 25 YEAR
   AND my_datetime <  CURDATE() + 1 DAY
```

That will pick up all the values of my_datetime prior to, but not including, midnight tomorrow.

Notice that you can use extremely large values (double precision floating point) in your INTERVAL clauses. For example, these two values yield the same result.

```
NOW()+ INTERVAL 100000 DAY
NOW()+ INTERVAL 8640000000000000 MICROSECOND
```

Comment: Can i use DateAdd method in mysql?

" BETWEEN DATEADD('SS', ?, now()) and now()